# src\polyfills.ts depends on 'core-js/es6/parse-float'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I got this error as soon as starting debug

> c:\proj\src\polyfills.ts depends on 'core-js/es6/symbol'. CommonJS or
> AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts. For more info see:
> https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

Based on the guidance above, add

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["loadash"],  // <-- add this key
```

Also appended `src/polyfills.ts` won't help either. Angular version 11.

Comment: Add core-js to allowedCommonJsDependencies

Comment: @danday74 Works and addresses another issue: VSC took 15 seconds to hit a breakpoint while F12 didn't. Please post your comment into an Answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add core-js to allowedCommonJsDependencies

Comment: Works like a charm. So take the root of whatever it depends on and add. For example, complaint is _'c:\proj\src\polyfills.ts depends on 'core-js/es6/symbol'_, take `core-js` and add. Thank you!